# Unable to connect to the Internet due to new router not having an RJ11 port

Tags: wireless-router

My Internet supplier, AT&T, provides a standard phone line to connect to the Internet. My new Trendnet AC1750 router only has gigabit Ethernet ports, which are not compatible with the standard phone connection.

What needs to be done to utilize the new router and connect to the Internet?
I am technically not very savvy and require some input. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need a DSL modem. Most routers that you buy yourself don't come with built-in DSL modems or cable modems. They expect you to already have a modem (or crappy router with built-in modem) from your DSL or Cable broadband Internet Service Providers (ISPs).

Most routers that *would* have those modems built-in are the ones that are provided by the DSL or Cable ISPs. But as routers go, they're usually crappy.

So the usual setup is to buy a "good" router like you did, and plug it into the LAN port on the back of the DSL modem or router that your ISP provided, and then disable all the crappy router functions on the ISP-provided box, so it just acts as a modem, and use your "good" router as the router.

I don't understand why AT&T didn't provide you with a DSL modem as part of signing up for service. It's pretty common for a DSL modem to be part of a "self-install kit" that they ship you when you sign up for DSL service. Or did you previously have one, but it died, which is why you bought the TrendNet box? It may be that you need to buy a separate DSL modem.